# SLS3.2.10, what's wrong about invariance here?

Tags: scala, covariance, invariance

Scala newbie running into a problem here:

```
val cache: LoadingCache[Long, String] = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
    .maximumSize(1000)
    .expireAfterWrite(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
    .build(
      new CacheLoader [Long, String] {
        override def load(key: Long): String = key.toString
      })
```

And got build time error: 
    Error:(12, 11) type mismatch;
     found   : com.google.common.cache.LoadingCache[Long,String]
     required: com.google.common.cache.LoadingCache[Long,String]
     Note: Long <: Long, but Java-defined trait LoadingCache is invariant in type K.
    You may wish to investigate a wildcard type such as `_ <: Long`. (SLS 3.2.10)
    .build(

What's the right fix here? Why the code is wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing `Long` with `java.lang.Long` everywhere (you'll still be able to access it with `Long` keys thanks to autoboxing). I remember having similar errors with generic types defined in Java when using primitives as type parameters.

Comment: That did the trick! Thanks! There is quite a number of such kind of tricks in Scala. Sometime frustrating.

Comment: In this case you should probably accept the answer.